# Javascript: Splicing all instances of element in Array

Tags: javascript, splice

I am trying to splice all instances of some defined value from an array.

```
    filterfunc: function(anyArray){
      for(var i = 0; i <anyArray.length; i++){
        var v = anyArray[i];
          for(var j = 1; j <arguments.length; j++){
           if(v == arguments[j]){
              anyArray.splice(i,1);
            }
          }
        } 
          return anyArray;
      },
```

I pass an array along with the arguments that I don't want.

The problem I encounter is that the splice function does not splice all instances of the  value.

ex:  `filterfunc([1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6],2,3);` 
the result: [1,2,3,3,4,5,6]

I want it to return [1,4,5,6]

Comment: What criteria are you using to decide if you remove a value from an array or not?

Comment: if the array passed "anyArray" contains anyone of the other arguments passed. So I increment through anyArray checking if any element is the same as the arguments[j]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not good in JavaScript, but deleting array items decrease their size and in such case is good to loop through in backward order.

```
for(var i = anyArray.length-1; i>0; i--){
   var v = anyArray[i];
   for(var j = 1; j <arguments.length; j++){
      if(v == arguments[j]){
         anyArray.splice(i,1);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would instead send a second array such as: `filterfunc([1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6],[2,3])` and use `Array.prototype.filter()`:

```
function filterfunc(a, b) {
  return a.filter(function(x) { return b.indexOf(x) == -1; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an i-- after you splice otherwise the string will shorten and then you will miss out values to be considered:

http://jsfiddle.net/6HatJ/1/

```
function filterfunc(anyArray){
  for(var i = 0; i <anyArray.length; i++){
    var v = anyArray[i];
      for(var j = 1; j <arguments.length; j++){
       if(v == arguments[j]){
          anyArray.splice(i,1);
           i--;
        }
      }
    } 
      return anyArray;
  };
```

Comment: note that you're adding "var" here as if it's block scoped, whereas JS is function scoped. Move all those var declarations to outside of the loops (var i,v,j; for(i=...) etc. =).

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) contains alot of useful helper functions and [uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) might be just what you are looking for.

If you just want that function and not the entire library you´d just have a look at the [source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-47).

Comment: I do not want to use underscore.js

Answer (score 0):

anyArray.splice(...) changes the number of elements in the array and therefore the indexes of the existing ones. You should decrease index by one each time you delete an element

```
anyArray.splice(i--,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use forEach, and also observe that splice is an in-place function. Returning the array just gives us a reference that we already had:

```
function remove(arr,elements) {
  elements.forEach(function(e) {
    for(var i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
      if(arr[i]==e) { arr.splice(i,1); }
    }
  });
}

// test
var a = [1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7],
    b  = [3,5,7];
remove(a,b);
a;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a while loop.

```
function removeInstanceOfElement(elem, arr)
{
    var index = 0;

    while(index < arr.length)
    {
        if(arr[index] == elem)
        {
            arr.splice(index, 1);
            index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ++index;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reduce to go through the array with splice. Here is a simple example using splice with reduce

Say we have an array a and want to remove all instances of 'd'

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'd'];
a.reduce((prevValReturned, currVal, currIndex, array) =>{
  if (currVal == 'd') a.splice(currIndex, 1);
}, 0);
```

Viewing the array a in the console you see that it is now

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

However splice is order n on each call, shifting all successive elements. If working with very large data set might be better to just loop through and use push

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'd'];
b= []
a.reduce((prevValReturned, currVal, currIndex, array) =>{
  if (currVal != 'd') b.push(currVal);
}, 0)
```

Of course this does not mutate array a. Viewing array b in the console you see

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```